# How to open a file in Excel from the command line

Tags: ms-office, command-line

Is it possible to tell Excel to open a file from the command line?

In Linux, I could do this using the command

```
libreoffice --calc test.xlsx
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the open command:

*This will use the default application for the file type, which may not be the desired application.*

```
open test.xlsx
```

or, to specify the application explicitly:

```
open test.xlsx -a /Applications/Microsoft\ Office\ 2011/Microsoft\ Excel.app/
```

or even,

```
open test.xlsx -a "Microsoft Excel"
```

A really useful way of doing this is to make an alias to Excel (in your `.bash_profile`)

```
alias xl='open -a "Microsoft Excel"'
```

Then you can just type the following to open an file in Excel:

```
xl file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that the `open` command exists, and that there are so many different ways to do it.

Comment: The first example will open the file with its default application.  On my system, that is LibreOffice.

Comment: Good point, @WGroleau. I'll adjust the text above...

Answer (score 0):

To open the excel file from the directory, this is the command you should use

```
libreoffice --calc /Path/Of/The/Directory/Excel.xlsx
```

To open new excel file use

```
libreoffice --calc
```